# jQuery toggling display css attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to get one of my links to dynamically show when an anchor href link gets clicked on.

The JavaScript code to show the cats link but it's not showing the cats link as follows:

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $("#cat").show();
});
```

```css
ul > li > #cat {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Dogs</a></li>
  <li><a id="cat" href="javascript:void(0);">Cats</a></li>
</ul>

<p>Cool cats are stored here</p>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button">Press here to enable Cats</a>
```

Comment: How you hide it by default ? it may that the _li_ that was hidden by default nor the anchor _a_.

Comment: used some css. Added cs code that was used to hide the link

Comment: Show us the css please.

Comment: I think you are using more then one same `id=cat` . see your code is working good https://fiddle.jshell.net/mo6xwzmn/

Comment: yeah you're right, I messed up some part of my css code

Answer (score 0):

you'll need `display:hidden` as default CSS for `#cat`, then `$("#cat").show()` will have effect. If you want the button to toggle the show state then use `$("#cat").toggle()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if isn't dynamically generated, if so you should use event delegation `on()` :

```
$("body").on("click", ".button", function() {
   $("#cat").show();
});
```

**NOTE:** Make sure that your code is wrapped by ready function.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $("#cat").show();
  });
});
```

```css
ul > li > #cat {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Dogs</a></li>
  <li><a id="cat" href="javascript:void(0);">Cats</a></li>
</ul>

<p>Cool cats are stored here</p>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button">Press here to enable Cats</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

CSS

```
ul > li > #cat {
  display: none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  $("#cat").toggle();
});
```

Here is the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/u0ajrpw0/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the **link** on **page load** by default using  `$("#cat").hide();`in the `$(document).ready(function(){}`

Check the snippet. Hope this helps

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cat").hide();
$(".button").click(function() {
    $("#cat").show();
});
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Dogs</a></li>
    <li><a id="cat" href="javascript:void(0);">Cats</a></li>
</ul>

<p>Cool cats are stored here</p>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button">Press here to enable Cats</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving this a quick demo in codepen, the following code (and codepen example) would be how I'd set up what you're trying to do.

The HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="dogs.html">
      Dogs
    </a>
  </li>
  <!-- you want to hide the LI, because if you hide the <a>, then
       there will be an empty <li> that you'll need to deal with in
       the layout of your page / screen reader users may end up
       wondering why there is an empty list item
   -->
  <li id="cats_item" class="display-none">
    <a href="cats.html">
      Cats
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<p id="reveal_message">
  Reveal a link to cats via the following button:
  <!--
    Use a button here since you're triggering an action
    on the page, and not actually linking anywhere.
  -->
  <button type="button" id="reveal_button">
    Reveal Cats
  </button>
</p>
```

The CSS

```
/* this is all you need to hide any element */
.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

The jQuery

```
$('#reveal_button').on('click', function () {
  // reveal the LI that contains the cats link
  $('#cats_item').show();
  /* hide the reveal message, since cats is shown, 
     this no longer has any usefulness (or change the message 
     and action to a 'toggle' to show/hide the cat link
  */
  $('#reveal_message').hide();
  /* 
    move keyboard focus to the cats link, otherwise
    keyboard users would have to traverse back up the
    DOM to get to the newly revealed link
  */
  $('#cats_item a').focus();
});
```

Here is a codepen that reveals the cat link on button click:
http://codepen.io/scottohara/pen/VbYyGr

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the jQuery Cdn in the html file?

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Or you can use this to hide as well.

```
$('#cat').hide();
```